# Regex a datetime from JSON and convert to miliseconds

Tags: json, datetime, regular-expressions

I've JSON like this:

`"to" : "2013-11-28T20:58:00.000+0000",`

Which I want to make into:

`"to" : "/Date(1296547200000)/",`

The furthest I got with regex is `replaceAll('(?m)(?i)"from" : "(.+?)("$)', '$2');`, but obviously that is not working, not sure about groupings, etc.

Now with date format conversion know it should be possible to achieve using getTime(), however, testing with my sample strings Invalid Date/time format error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it using a utility function like this:

```
public class JsonDate {
    class Info {
        public datetime to;
    }
    public static DateTime testDate(String dateString) {
        return ((info)json.deserialize(dateString, info.class)).to;
    }
    public static DateTime testDate2(String dateString) {

    }
}
```

Using the code:

```
DateTime d = JsonDate.testDate('{ "to" : "2013-11-28T20:58:00.000+0000" }');
```

Or, you can use the generic parser:

```
public class JsonDate {
    public static DateTime testDate(String dateString) {
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(dateString);
        parser.nextToken();
        parser.nextValue();
        return parser.getDateTimeValue();
    }
}
```

Called as:

```
DateTime d = JsonDate.testDate('{ "to" : "2013-11-28T20:58:00.000+0000" }');
```

From either method, you can then use `DateTime.getTime()` to get your timestamp. It would then be trivial to convert it to whatever other format you desire.